# JQuery fadeTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this code so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $( ".top-bg" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
    }
```

The idea is a menu with low opacity and when I scroll down, it fades in but the problem is that I can't bring it back to low opacity (0.7) when I scroll back up to <400.

I have been searching around and I didn't find my solution.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write one more condition if < 400 then opacity what you want.

Comment: And you'll want to not repeat the `fadeTo` each time the window scrolls (which you are currently), but only when it *crosses a boundary* from `<= 400` to `> 400` or back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues there. First, you never check for `scrollTop` being `<= 400`, so of course it's not going to go back.

The second is that even with the code you have, you're constantly re-applying the `fadeTo`, any time the window scrolls, even if it was already `> 400`.

```
var fadedIn = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var thisScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (thisScroll > 400 && !fadedIn) {
        $( ".top-bg" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
        // Or with a stop: $( ".top-bg" ).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
        fadedIn = true;
    } else if (thisScroll <= 400 && fadedIn) {
        $( ".top-bg" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.7);
        // Or with a stop: $( ".top-bg" ).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.7);
        fadedIn = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1879457: Glad that helped. You might want a `.stop()` in there before each of the `.fadeTo`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $( ".top-bg" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
    }else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 400)
{
        $( ".top-bg" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.7);
}
```

Comment: What will constantly re-trigger the fades in appropriately.